# what does the docker daemon option --selinux-enabled do

Tags: docker, selinux

I guess it will label the containers it started, but from the output of `ps -eZ`, I don't see any difference.
For example, the container `etcd` has the same domain, no matter the daemon is with and without this option:

```
system_u:system_r:container_runtime_t:s0 16212 ? 00:00:00 dnsmasq-nanny
```

But it does prevent my container(k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64:1.14.8) from starting up and the deny logs shows access to `/etc/localtime` and /usr/sbin/dnsmasq are denied. I think these are files inside container filesystem. How can I write SELinux policy to allow access inside container file system?

Comment: I checked in my env. again, 
before turn on the option, the contained is of type: "container_runtime_t", 
and after turn on the option, it is: "container_t".
container_runtime_t is an alias of docker_t and is an unconfined type, so the container can run without problem, while container_t is a confined type, it prevents the container from accessing some mislabled content.
The log info of some denial of access  to container internal file system might be misleading,and they do not repeat after applying a policy module generated using audit2allow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Short Answer

- `--selinux-enabled` will enable an selinux policy which allows container processes labelled with `svirt_lxc_net_t` to read and write to files with the `svirt_sandbox_file_t` label.
- Container labels can be checked by inspecting the container using `docker inspect -f '{{ .ProcessLabel }}' <container name>` and `docker inspect -f '{{ .MountLabel }}' <container name>`

#### Long Answer

The `--selinux-enabled` option enables the docker selinux security policy, which is described in detail [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/container_security_guide/docker_selinux_security_policy). When enabled, this policy will:

- Label containers with the `svirt_sandbox_file_t` and `svirt_lxc_net_t` labels. This can be confirmed by running a container, and checking the labels applied to it:

  ```
  docker inspect <container id> | grep "Label"

  "MountLabel": "system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0:c557,c611",
  "ProcessLabel": "system_u:system_r:svirt_lxc_net_t:s0:c557,c611",
  ```

  The `svirt_sandbox_file_t` is a MountLabel which restricts access to files on the host filesystem. The [docker selinux docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/container_security_guide/docker_selinux_security_policy) say:

  > If a file is labeled svirt_sandbox_file_t, then by default all containers can read it. But if the containers write into a directory that has svirt_sandbox_file_t ownership, they write using their own category

  The category in the example above is `c557,c611`.

  The `svirt_lxc_net_t` is used to protect processes. According to the redhat solution [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2429071), it is used to:

  > ... isolate the container processes from the host, and it generates a unique Multi-Category Security label to allow SELinux to prevent one container process from attacking other container processes and content.

Your access issue is most likely occurring because the selinux labels on the host filesystem are preventing access from within the container. For example, the [selinux docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/container_security_guide/docker_selinux_security_policy) say:

> By default, docker gets access to everything in /usr and most things in /etc.

So your options are to either:

1. Manually relabel the files on the hosts system with `system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t`. This is often not recommended for system files and directories as it can have unintended effects on the host.
2. Run the container as an unconfined type. This will disable isolation for this container only while still continuing to enforce selinux on the host:

   ```
   docker run -it --security-opt label:disable alpine sh
   ```