# Cannot list contents of nested directory in Docker: Permission denied

Tags: docker, permissions, dockerfile

I've found that I cannot list the contents of a nested directory in a Docker container.

File structure:

```
├── Dockerfile
└── foo
    └── bar
        └── baz.txt
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian

COPY foo /app/foo

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["ls", "foo/bar"]
```

I can run `ls foo/bar/` successfully on the host machine:

```
$ ls foo/bar/
baz.txt
```

But when I run the container, I get a "Permission denied" error.

```
$ docker build -t foo .

$ docker run foo
ls: cannot open directory 'foo/bar': Permission denied
```

I don't understand why permission is denied, because I'm the root user in the container, and the directory seems to have the appropriate permissions:

```
$ docker run -it foo sh
# whoami
root
# cd foo
# ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug  3 19:13 bar
```

Environment:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
```

Host machine: Fedora 32

Comment: Kindly share your docker version, and whether you're running on RHEL/CentOS.

Comment: @hilsenrat Thanks, I've now added that info to the question.

Comment: Take a look at this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033599/what-does-the-docker-daemon-option-selinux-enabled-do). Since you're running Fedora, I assume that you have some kind of issue with `SELinux` and the `container-selinux` package.

Comment: I suspect it's a SELinux issue. Please verify that SELinux is enabled, configuration of the docker engine (`docker info`), and any other SELinux settings you've configured.

Comment: You were right that it was related to SElinux. I edited `/etc/sysconfig/docker` to delete the `--selinux-enabled` option, and restarted the docker daemon. It worked after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from the comments:

The problem was caused by SElinux which is enabled by default on Fedora.

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/docker` to remove `--selinux-enabled` from the `OPTIONS` variable.

Restart the docker daemon.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Run the container. There's no need to rebuild the image.

```
$ docker run foo
baz.txt
```